# Group rows by similar value composition

Tags: python, r, algorithm, sorting, data-analysis

I am looking for a good way to group the rows of a data frame - group, not combine or melt them - according to how much values are the same or have a certain range of similarity.
For example if I had a data frame like

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a", "a", "b", "c"), B = c(1, 6, 1, 7), C = c(1000, 20, 900, 50))
df
#   A B    C
# 1 a 1 1000
# 2 a 6   20
# 3 b 1  900
# 4 c 7   50
```

I would like the rows 1 and 3 grouped because they both have low values in B and high values in C compared to the other two. My actual data frame has 12 or so columns with strings and numeric values. I'd like to group those rows that have perfect matches for some key string columns and have close values in at least four numeric columns. 
I am quite good with R but new to python or other languages though if you have a solution in whatever language I will start learning it.

Thank you very much for any suggestion, function, package or library name or even whole sollutions! I excuse my english, it got rusty over the last years.

Comment: your objective is too poorly-defined

Comment: `df$group <- cut(df$C, 2)`, though you might want to set breaks in a more robust fashion, i.e. quantiles or the like.

Comment: I don't know exactly where you are going with this but maybe you want to cluster the data with a cluster analysis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)?